# Is there another term for “complete closure”?

Tags: terminology

I want to describe a function $f$ which, on set $S$, satisfies these properties:
$$
\forall x\in S.f\ x\in S \\
\forall y\in S.\exists x\in S.f\ x=y
$$
One example is the successor function upon $\mathbb Z$, and one non-example is the successor function upon $\mathbb N$ (because $\nexists x\in\mathbb N.\text{succ}\ x=0)$.

Is there a commonly understood word for this, or should I just define my own term? In the title, I suggest “$f$ is completely closed over $S$”. As with standard closure, this term can expand to describe n-ary functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two statements given in your question are precisely
$$f(x) \in S \qquad \forall x\in S$$
i.e. $f: S\to S$ is a function and
$$\forall y\in S \exists x\in S: f(x) = y$$
i.e. $f(S) = S$ or $f$ is surjective.

If your notation reflects what you want to call "completely closed", it is nothing other than a surjective function from a set $S$ to itself.

Comment: I may have missed something from the conditions. It should be the case that $f\ S=S$ and $f^{-1}\ S=S$ (and unique $f^{-1}$ exists because the function is bijective). Also, $S$ should be the image of $f$, not just the codomain.

Comment: @JamesWood Then you're at "$f$ is a bijection of $S$ to itself". Note that the two statements _do not_ imply injectivity (Consider $x\mapsto \lfloor \frac x2 \rfloor$ on $S=\mathbb N$)

Comment: My original conditions were right, but my deductions were wrong. Thanks for the counterexample!

Answer (score 0):

Such a function is called [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective). More generally, it applies to function $f : X \to Y$ even when the codomain is not equal to the domain: $f$ is called surjective when for all $y \in Y$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: Yep. $\;\!$ Or onto, but I prefer surjective.

Comment: I want something stricter than that, more related to closure than surjectiveness/injectiveness. I also consider the function that maps integers to their decimal without 0 representation to be a non-example, despite it being bijective. Would “self-bijective” work, or does that sound too much like “identity”? Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: @JamesWood What do you mean by "Integer without $0$ representation"? What would $100$ map to and what would map to $100$?

Comment: @JamesWood: What do you want, exactly? What you wrote is just a surjective function from $S$ to itself. You can call it "self-surjective" (a bit ugly) or a "surjective endomorphism", if you want, but surjectivity (or "onto", or "epimorphism") is the essential word.

Comment: @AlexR [Bijective numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_without_a_zero#The_bijective_base-10_system). The number 100 maps to “9A”, and “100” is not in the range of the function. As for the argument for “surjective”, I'll think more about it.

Comment: @JamesWood Well, that's not even a function of $S\to S$, since the domain and codomain are different ($\{0,\ldots,9\}^{\mathbb N} \to \{1, \ldots, 9, A\}^{\mathbb N}$)

Comment: @AlexR It's a non-example, but surjective. Hence, “surjective” alone is not what I wanted.

Comment: @JamesWood Ah okay I see the problem. NB that using the bijection of "relabelling" $A$ to $0$, you get a function wich fulfills your requirements.